# Rendering all PartialViews for a Controller at one time

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, backbone.js, razor

I am using .NET MVC4 and have created a number of PartialViews that are all used as templates. I use Backbone.js and Backbone.Marionette.js for my client-side code and have created the templates used in my Backbone Views as RAZOR PartialViews.

I created a Controller called TemplatesController that has a ChildAction and given a name of  PartialView it returns the MvcHtmlString for that PartialView which is my template. I can then use the template along with Handlebars to create my View in Backbone.Marionette.

This all works great for me but I have to call the Controller action for every PartialView that exists. My list of templates is growing and I would like to not have to add a new call render the template every time to my Index View.

My question is, is there a better way to just call the Controller once and return all PartialViews that exist? Thanks for any suggestions.

Here is my Controller method

```cs
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GetTemplate(string name) {
    return PartialView(name); 
}
```

Here is a HtmlHelper Method I use to call the Controller Action

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString Template(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name) {  
    // call ChildAction on our controller to get the HTML for this template 
    return htmlHelper.Action("GetTemplate", "Templates", new { name = name });
}
```

Here is example of how I load templates into Index or _Layout view using Helper. For each PartialView I create I add a line but I would like to remove these and do it in one line such as Html.AllTemplates or something.

```razor
@Html.Template("SiteHeader")
@Html.Template("SiteFooter")
```

I stripped all the content out but this would be example of what would be in each of the partial views, the main thing to note is it is wrapped inside a script tag

```razor
<script id="site-header" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <h3>{{headertext}}</h3>
  <div>{{somevalue}}</div>
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of having partial views? Why not just move all the partial views into one view if you need them all at once.

Comment: Good point, I agree about the purpose of PartialViews. For organization I prefer to have them in separate files and some of them can get pretty involved. It could have been done as html files instead of cshtml or could have simply just placed them all on the Index View itself. It has made it easier to manage them in individual files.